# Oracle PLSQL - Declare a cursor on a non-existing table

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor, ora-00942

I want to declare a cursor on a table that does not exist. Of course, my procedure doesnt compile.

This table is a temporary table, and is created by a pre process. It will exist on runtime, but at compile time its another story.

For my select / updates an other DML operations, I've used

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'operation from tmp_table'`

but I can't find a workaround for cursors.

Is there a way?

Basically, i want this to compile

```
drop table test;

/*from this on should compile*/
DECLARE
cursor c is select * from test;

BEGIN
  for reg in c LOOP
  /*...*/
  END LOOP;
END;
```

## update

So far not compiling:

```
SQL> declare
  2  c sys_refcursor;
  3  BEGIN
  4  open c for 'select * from pepito'; -- 'pepito' does not exist
  5  close c;
  6  end;
  7  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Should use CREATE PROCEDURE, thanks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get the exception since you actually run the code. Replace your `declare` by a `CREATE PROCEDURE test_cursor AS` to compile the code.

Comment: TOAD has no compile button. :S This should be trivial !!!

Comment: "DECLARE..BEGIN..END;/" means "compile and run this anonymous block". This is why you're getting ORA-00942. CREATE PROCEDURE ...;/" means "compile and create this procedure". You won't get ORA-00942 then, until you call the procedure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to define your cursor like this:

```
DECLARE
  c SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN c FOR 'SELECT * FROM dual';
  CLOSE c;
END;
```

You can also bind arguments:

```
OPEN c FOR 'SELECT * FROM dual WHERE DUMMY = :1' USING 'X';
```

---

For further information see the Oracle documentation of the [OPEN-FOR Statement](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/openfor_statement.htm#i35231).

Example using a stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test IS
  c SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN c FOR 'SELECT * FROM fdfdfdfdfd';
  CLOSE c;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, but dual is an existing table. I need to do that for a not existing table at run time.

Comment: typo there, its compile time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can also change the provided source by 'SELECT * FROM some_not_existing_table'. It will compile fine and break at runtime if the table still does not exist.

Comment: I'm getting a 'table or view does not exist' in sqlplus

Comment: IMO it should work as expected. Tom, I think you are doing it wrong somehow.

Comment: @ammoQ I agree it compiles when using dual, but not when using an unexisting table. I added ann example to my question

Comment: A stored procedure does compile.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test IS
  c SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN c FOR 'SELECT * FROM fdfdfdfdfd';
  CLOSE c;
END;
/
It will not execute, and a top-level anonymous block will fail when it tries to execute

Answer (score 5):

Creating temporary tables as required is usually not considered good practice in Oracle, where Global Temporary Tables are better and would not cause this problem

Comment: +1 Global Temporary Tables are so much better than creating/destroying tables on the fly. Creating tables on the fly is much more error-prone and harder to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

You can use DBMS_SQL to get even more flexibility than the ref cursor method described by Peter Lang. But it means more work, too.